# Can't open 2 FILE *

Tags: c, file, raspberry-pi, printf

I was working on a program in C for Raspberry PI development, and I've been getting this weird bug.

I honestly have no clue regarding its origins. The program is very simple so far.

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file; 
    FILE *file2; 
    FILE *peak1;
    FILE *peak2; 
    file = fopen("input0.txt", "a+"); 
    file2 = fopen("input1.txt", "a+"); 
    peak1=fopen("peak1.txt", "a+");
    peak2=fopen("peak2.txt", "a+");

    fprintf(file, "%s\n", "HELLO!");
    fprintf(peak1, "%s\n", "HELLO!");
}
```

**Bug:-**

When I run the program and check the outputs to the files, Only `'input0.txt'` has `"HELLO!"` written where as `'peak1.txt'` has nothing.
I can write to the first two files `file` and `file2`, but cannot write to the second two files `peak1` and `peak2`.

I have tried writing multiple things but to no avail. What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `fclose(FILE *)` at the end. Calling [`int fclose(FILE *fp);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose) will ensure the file descriptor is properly disposed of and output buffers flushed so the data written to the file will be present in the file on disk.

From: [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fclose.html):

> [int fclose(FILE *stream);](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fclose.html)
>   The `fclose()` function shall cause the stream pointed to by stream to
>   be flushed and the associated file to be closed. **Any unwritten
>   buffered data for the stream shall be written to the file;** any unread
>   buffered data shall be discarded. Whether or not the call succeeds,
>   the stream shall be disassociated from the file and any buffer set by
>   the `setbuf()` or `setvbuf()` function shall be disassociated from the
>   stream. If the associated buffer was automatically allocated, it shall
>   be deallocated.

Comment: additionally you have included to many header files, I don't know about your project but for code you posted you only need `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Yeah, I recognize that. I intend for my program to do much more later on, and I know I'll be needing those headers in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @MEric *`why then can I write to the first two files (file/file2) if I don't close them either?`* -- because its doesn't means only after `fclose()` data written to the disk... but `fclose()` make it sure before close file. Read my first lines in answer.-- Get it **?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `fclose(FILE *)` at the end of your code.

The `C` library function int `fclose(FILE *stream)` closes the stream. All buffers are flushed.

Comment: Okay, I will add that. However, why then can I write to the first two files (file/file2) if I don't close them either?